# Create a class. Add the following methods: min, max, isEven, square. In the main method, call those methods

Tags: java

So I'm trying to create a class called hw8 and some method in the class to find min, max of 2 numbers, check Even number and calculate square of one of the number however, I got some error like this and I can't find the solution since I'm a beginner in java.

```
hw8.java:42: error: method isEven in class hw8 cannot be applied to given types;
                MyMath.isEven();
                      ^
  required: int
  found:    no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Here is the code

```
import java.util.*;

public class hw8{

public hw8(int a, int b){

}

public void min(int a, int b){
    if(a > b){
        System.out.println(b);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
public void max(int a, int b){
    if(a > b){
        System.out.println(a);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
public void isEven(int a){
    boolean condition = true;
    if(a%2==0){
        System.out.println(condition);
    }
    else{
        condition = false;
        System.out.println(condition);
    }
}
public void square(int b){
    int sq = b * b;
    System.out.println(sq);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    hw8 MyMath = new hw8(3, 4);
    MyMath.isEven();
}
```

}

Comment: The error message explains, very specifically, what the problem is. Maybe google "what's an argument in java" if you don't understand it

Comment: Do you really want the methods to print something?   Normally, the actual min or max of the two arguments would be returned.   And the `isEven` method would return true if even or false if not.

Answer (score 1):

Since you specified that `isEven` needs an argument (you defined it inside the parentheses next to the name of the method), you need to provide one when calling the method:

```
MyMath.isEven(8); // added 8
```

Plus, I do not think you need create an instructor since you do not use it:

```
// remove this
public hw8(int a, int b){

}
...
hw8 MyMath = new hw8(); // notice that I removed the numbers
```

Comment: Typo: instructor